# Getting HDD Serial Number with Intel Optane Disk

Tags: node.js, windows, electron, wmic

I am developing an application that users can use their accounts on only one computer. I decided to use the Disk Manufacturer Serial Number to identify the computers. After a while, I noticed that the serial numbers of the devices using the Intel Optane Memory were identical.
How do i get the serial number on this condition?

In Windows I access the serial number using "wmic diskdrive" and get a value like this :

```
Intel Optane+932GB \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0 Optane_0000
```

I use the following code on the terminal:

```
wmic diskdrive get name, caption, SerialNumber
```

Comment: So are you asking how to get the same result as wmic from javascript?  Or is the wmic result a problem (not unique)?

Comment: Please also note that your attempt at node locked licensing will fail as soon as anyone installs your software inside a virtual machine.

Comment: I can take results from wmic. The problem is wmic gives me this results on computer with optane.

Thank you for virtual machine information, i take more than one information with my tokens. This is not a high priority reason for my audience but If you have any advice I would be happy to know

Comment: The problem right now is that you don't have a programming question.  You don't even know if the Optane devices have machine-readable persistent unique serial numbers.  That seems to be more of a hardware product feature question.  Once you have either some documentation describing it or evidence of another program reading it, then you can ask here for help turning that knowledge into code / making your attempt at coding it work.